# Proving the Lying over for Integral Ring Homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

It is well-known that if $A\subset B$ is an integral extension, then given a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ there exists a prime ideal
$\mathfrak{q} \subset B$ such that $A \cap \mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}$

I am trying to generalize  this.

> If we have an integral homomorphism $f:A \to B$ and assume $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ is a prime ideal of $A$ containing $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ then there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \subset B$ such that $\mathfrak{p}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$

What I tried.

> If $\operatorname{ker}(f) \subset
> \mathfrak{p}$, then consider the map $\frac{A}{\operatorname{ker}(f)}\to B$, then this map is the inclusion map, and hence there exist $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\frac{\mathfrak{p}}{\operatorname{ker}(f)}$. How do I conclude from this. Am I on  right path?

Comment: Can you just use that the prime ideals lying over $\ker(f)$ are exactly the prime ideals of $A/\ker(f)$?

Comment: @walkar, can not get you. Can you suggest how to complete the proof using the notations I used.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ factors into $A\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}\overline{A}:=A/\operatorname{ker}f\overset{\overline{f}}{\longrightarrow}B$. There is a bijective correspondence between ideals of $A$ containing $\operatorname{ker}f$ and ideals of $\overline{A}$ which is given by:
$$ I\subset A \mapsto \pi (I), \\ J\subset \overline{A} \mapsto \pi^{-1}( J).$$
Moreover, it preserves primeness so that $\pi(\mathfrak{p})$ is prime in $\overline{A}$.

On the otherhand, we can think of $\overline{A}$ as a subring of $B$ through $\overline{f}$, and $B$ is still integral over $\overline{A}$. Thus, there exists a prime $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$ lying over $\pi (\mathfrak{p})$. In fact, we have $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$ which is easily seen by a set-theoretic argument.

Comment: Fair Enough great!!!